# ODBC Connection in Project.params | SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, odbc, oledb

i need help establing ODBC Connection in project params in my SSIS.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong or I missed some steps.

My Source connection fails when im using my ODBC connection in project params.
But when I use package level ODBC Connection, it is working.

Error is:

> [C8PF [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWQPu.png)] Error: The AcquireConnection method call to the connection
>   manager FBEQ failed with error code 0xC0014009.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.

Highlighted in yellow are set to project.params

[image]
[image]

my odbc configuration:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that the main problem is in the ODBC Connectionstring provided in the parameter, click on the local package connection manager and press F4 to show the properties Tab. Go to Connectionstring property and check the syntax used. Try to use the same syntax in the parameter value.

Another thing to try, is providing an empty password in the connection string:

```
DSN=myDsn;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=;
```

- [connectionstrings - System DSN](https://www.connectionstrings.com/odbc-dsn/system-dsn/)

Comment: Adding empty Password like "Pwd=;" works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Same - just one thing to add for clarity added in "pwd=;" to the connection string AND set the password project param to correct password. Thank you!